# Reseed Identity Field in Redshift?

Tags: amazon-redshift

I need to leave a gap in my Redshift table's identity field.  Is there a way to reseed the identity?  If so, what is the syntax?

e.g.
have loaded record-id (which is an identity field) 1 thru 3,000,000

want to leave a gap of 1,000,000 records

resume loading records having record-id 4,000,001 and up.

So, I'd want to reseed record-id to 4,000,001.

Answer (score 1):

Got a response from Amazon on this.  They say it is NOT possible.